# How can I remove items from my wishlist in Steam?

Tags: steam

I was unable to find a link to remove a game from the list (in the web interface at least)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You want to go to view your wishlist: ([yours is here](http://steamcommunity.com/id/kromak/wishlist))

[image]
<sup>*(not my wishlist)*</sup>

While viewing your wishlist, you will notice the "Added on" line below the title.
At the end of this line, there is a remove link. Use this remove link to remove an item from your wishlist.

[image]

Do note that you need to be logged in to be able to remove iitems from your wishlist.

Comment: I can't believe I missed that! -- Is it me or it can use a re-design? (I was looking in the "Links" drop down, in the right, at the top, but did not see it there)

Comment: I think it's okayish, but I see your point. I think the dropdown was added very recently, this really changed the situation but the 'Remove' link wasn't reconsidered.

Comment: I don't have that link.. have they changed the design or is my account bunged?

Comment: O never mind.. it just logs me out everytime I turn around.

Comment: For those in mobile web/app, the link may not be viewable because the layout stacked against each other. *Solution:* view the web/app in landscape mode.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this from your [Steam Community](http://steamcommunity.com/) Profile page.  Go to the Games section, then click on the Wishlist tab.  From there you should see a remove link for each game.

Answer (score 2):

In the source by press F12 In Chrome, look for this `var g_rgWishlistData =` in there you can find the `appid`.

Go your wishlist page, press F12, go to Console, and insert this:

```
$J.post( g_strWishlistBaseURL + 'remove/', {
                'appid' : 0,
                'sessionid' : g_sessionID
});
```

Replace the appid with the id from the list, and press enter.

---

For example, The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim(Old one, hidden by Steam)'s `appid` is `72850`.
(as i said, In the source by press F12 In Chrome, look for this `var g_rgWishlistData =` in there you can find the `appid`.)
Go to your wishlist page, F12, Sources, and type the following text and Enter.

```
$J.post( g_strWishlistBaseURL + 'remove/', {
                'appid' : 72850,
                'sessionid' : g_sessionID
});
```

and it will removed from your wishing list.

Comment: This is good to know and shows a lot of effort, but it might be a little too technical for the crowd on this site.

Comment: This is a good answer though pretty technical, it might be useful for people looking to do a bit more manipulation of their wishlist. I have cleaned up your formatting a bit  so it is a bit more readable.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt Apparently there's a bug where wishlist items only disappear from view but still remain in the database, causing the counter in the list to be incorrect; see [this topic](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/3211505894120057593/). Games on the list that are removed from Steam [likewise get stuck in limbo](https://www.reddit.com/r/Steam/comments/9l2lu5/how_to_remove_games_removed_from_the_store_from/) and can never truly be removed. This solves that. The IDs on the wishlist can be fetched from [here](https://store.steampowered.com/dynamicstore/userdata/).